# An appropriate single word or phrase for "life-saving moment" please?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is my first question ever. Sorry for the lack of brevity. What word would describe a life-saving moment?

When my father was taken prisoner in WWII, he was prodded, by a soldier's bayonet in his spine, into a large tent. His arms were high in the air. A young private who looked very stressed was standing 10 feet in front of my father. He suddenly charged towards my captive father with his rifle's bayonet aimed at his abdomen. A sergeant quickly raised his leg and kicked the private's rifle aside so the bayonet missed my father's body by a couple of inches.

Decades later, as he held an infant, his first grandchild in his arms, my father muttered something about, "That sergeant's big boot." If not for that life-saving moment, not my dad, nor his son, nor his grandson would exist.

What word is appropriate for such a life-saving moment? Thanks very much.

Comment: If you don't mind religious overtones, maybe "moment of grace".

Answer (score 2):

A common idiom for this is ***brush with death***.

> [**brush with death**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/brush+with+death) - an instance of nearly dying.

This phrase has the benefit of not necessarily implying that the event is epiphanic or pivotal or character-changing.  It's just a mere *brush with death*, to make of it what you will.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using "[**life-and-death**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/life%E2%80%93and%E2%80%93death)" or "lifr-or-death" to describe the situation. It means:

> extremely important and serious especially because your survival or
>   life may depend on success

Your example:

> It was my father's life-or-death moment when the sergeant quickly
>   raised his leg and kicked the private's rifle aside so the bayonet
>   missed my father's body by a couple of inches.

[Merriam-Webster]

Answer (score 0):

***providential*** might fit the bill.

> Happening at a good time because of luck [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/providential)

Answer (score 0):

[***Salvation***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/salvation): *"If not for that salvation, not my dad, nor his son, nor his grandson would exist."*

> *3.a. preservation from destruction or failure*
>
> *3.b. deliverance from danger or difficulty*

[Merriam-Webster]

It's a bit on-the-nose, but then, that's sort of what we're going for...

---

FWIW, I'd use *neither* rather than *not*: *"If not for that salvation, neither my dad, nor his son, nor his grandson would exist."*

Answer (score -1):

My sentence:
***If the sergeant was late by a  whisker, my dad, nor his son, nor his grandson would be existing today!***